# Stack divs in 2x2 matrix

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div i need to show them in rows and column like

```
2x2
2x2
```

my html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"> <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" > </div>
</div>
```

Expected result

[image]

Comment: need to more info, like CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the same row pictures in a `<div>` tag, and use `<a>` tag to separate them to different columns (for doing some behavior like hyperlink `<a href="https:......">` ).

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">  
            <a>
                <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" >
            </a>
            <a>
                <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" >
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">  
            <a>
                <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" >
            </a>
            <a>
                <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it - basically using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/spandzfiddle/v4shup17/

Answer (score 0):

An answer to the question can be like this, using flexbox :

```css
.container{
  display : flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex : 1;
  }
  .row{
    display : flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  }
  .box img{
  border : 2px solid black;
  border-radius : 10px;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/2bb8b8/fff.png&text=Dummy+Image" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/2bb8b8/fff.png&text=Dummy+Image" > </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/2bb8b8/fff.png&text=Dummy+Image" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/2bb8b8/fff.png&text=Dummy+Image" > </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically the structure of the code is this :

```
.container

  |- .row

    |-.box img

    |-.box img

  |-.row

    |-.box img

    |-.box img
```

Wherein we set display of `.container` as flex and flex direction to row, means all the children will be stacked horizontal. Then we also set the display of `.row` as flex and flex direction to column so that the children will be stacked vertically. By this , we get the 2x2 grid as requested by you.

Comment: thanks but if i have 4 div in one div. mean you dividing 2 images in one div. i dont want to divide

Comment: I'm dividing 'cause I don't know the exact dimensions you might have. Images can be variable in number so diving can be the best option for this\

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS grid layout you can easily design your image grid without having to use floats and positioning.

**Styles**

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="grid">
        <div>   
            <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" />
            <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" />
            <img src="../../assets/img/demo.jpg" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why no one has recommended using *only* grid yet:

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 80px);
    grid-gap: 6px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120" > </div>
  <div class="box"> <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/120" > </div>
</div>
```